# minimal X.org xserver installation on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, xorg, software-installation, x-server

I installed *Debian Wheezy* with no desktop environment as I would like to use lightweight [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) window manager instead. However, as a first step, I need to install xserver. I would like to install minimal components needed for running the xserver. What are the exact components(binaries, libraries, configuration files, etc) needed to run xserver? Obviously xinit(starts X server session), but what else? Or are the components needed for running xserver so scattered that practically one needs to install *xserver-xorg* package which will handle all the dependencies needed?

Answer (score 12):

This should do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg-core \
    xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-fbdev \
    xserver-xorg-video-(yourcard, can be intel, nouveau, or ati)
```

Comment: As I have Intel 945GM video card, I need to install "xserver-xorg-video-intel" package, but why exactly is this needed? I mean at the moment, according to "lspci -vvv", I use i915.ko driver and it's able to show the picture. Or is the performance lot better with intel_drv.so driver which will be installed with "xserver-xorg-video-intel" package? Or is it a problem for xserver if the driver module runs in kernel space?

Comment: Although Intel graphics chipsets are now plug-n-play, it is recommended mainly for performance, in terms of video tearing, maximum resolution, etc. For example, the `intel_drv.so` driver particularly uses a `Triple Buffering` for vertical synchronization, this allows for full performance and avoids tearing. It also provides module-based powersaving options.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the Xorg driver with the kernel driver. Different requirements, different drivers, work best (and sometimes only) if used together matching.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `no-install-reccomends`, besides issues changing hardware there's some other side-effect? On upgrades/dist-upgrade for example?

Comment: I had to install xinit as well to get the xserver to start