# Unable to operate mouse in GUI on Ubuntu Server in VBox VM

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg, virtualbox, desktop-environment

Mouse can't work on Ubuntu Server (minmal virtual machine mode) in VBox VM.
I ran:

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends xserver-xorg-core
sudo aptitude install jwm
startx
```

output:

> -bash: startx: command not found.

**Update:** OK, xinit was missing.

**Update 2:** So I ran:

```
sudo aptitude --without-recommends install xinit
```

installation ok, then:

```
startx
```

output:

> /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc: 3: exec: /usr/bin/X: not found
>   xinit: giving up
>   xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
>   xinit: server error

**Update 3:** Some package were left out! So I purged all before mentioned and reinstalled all three except no --without-recommends flag this time.
Apparently I can access the simple graphical desktop but with problems. Mouse won't move.
Output from tty; can't roll up, it has cancel at this point (or has it ended outputing?)

> loading extension GLX
>   The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
>   Warning: Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but  has 2 symbols
>   Ignoring extra symbols
>   Erros from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server

**Update 4:** Installed guest additions and begins to master the game.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You also need `sudo apt-get install xinit` for `/usr/bin/startx`.

Comment: well done, but I would like hit for essential. I read question [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128860/minimal-x-org-xserver-installation-on-debian-wheezy) and realized they are xinits' fork. If I follow it up `xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel`, as my video chipset is intel, would it handle the basic graphic output (in place of xinit)?

Comment: Sorry I cannot get what you want to ask exactly.  You might as well [edit your post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/220059/edit) or open a new question to describe details clearly.

Comment: Have you looked for X in /usr/bin/? Also look in /etc/X11/. If you have it in/etc/X11/ you could try to link it in /usr/bin, but I'm not certain if this will work. Or try sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg-core    xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-fbdev

Comment: sorry, actually the output is for `startx`.  
how do I link it ?

Comment: ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink

Comment: There is no X folder in /usr/bin/ *but* has X11 and /etc/X11 also exists. I tried with those packages (input-all and video-fbdev) with no positive results. What should I do?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-core will remove all packages and configs installed by this package group. Try a fresh install of X without the --without-recomends. I'm afraid that you might be missing some vital packages this way. That is all I can give you since I'm not a guru.

Comment: help would be much appreciated.