# Installation of Firefox on Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install Firefox on Alpine Linux. I ran

```
$ sudo apk add firefox
```

And a few hundred MBs later, it installed.

However, when I ran `firefox`, it crashed with `symbol not found` errors and something to do with libmozgtk and gtk+.

How do I fix this or is it not possible to run Firefox on a musl-based distro?

Comment: Welcome, `sudo apk add firefox-esr`

Comment: Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install firefox on alpine linux enable the [Community Repository](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Community_Repository):

> add (or uncomment) a line like:
>
> ```
> http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
> ```

then run:

```
sudo apk update
sudo apk add firefox-esr
```

The package is called `firefox` on the [edge branch](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge):

> Warning: "edge" is under constant development so be careful using it in production. It is possible that bugs in "edge" could cause data loss or could break your system.

**Update**

As said @OrangeDog `firefox-esr` (and `firefox`) is now available on the `edge` and `v3.12` branch.

Comment: This works! Any difference between the packages though?

Comment: firefox-esr stands for "Extended Support Release". The difference with firefox is explained here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/

Comment: Firefox seems to have been removed in Alpine 3.11. Any ideas?

Comment: `firefox-esr` is now in edge too

Comment: @OrangeDog Thank you for this update, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have the extended os version and need a minimal desktop to start firefox, is there a tutorial for Alpine similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128875/72988) for debian? Would the [awesome](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Awesome(wm)_Setup) desktop be minimal, sounds as if?

Comment: @Timo Welcome! Sorry I can't find a good  answer for you. I encourage you to post a new question. I am interrested.

Comment: ok, I will wait for your reply;)